# We have x=0.2234 and Δx =0.2*10^-3.Find how many accurate digits does the number have?

Tags: numerical-methods

So we know that $Δx≤(1/2)*10^{-n}$ where n is the number of the accurate digits.
Now I just have to replace $Δx =0.2*10^-3$=$(1/2)*10^{-n}$ and find n.
But why have I been given x=0,2234 since I dont need it?

Comment: Reposted at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/778009/18398

Comment: What is your definition of *accurate digits*?  We cannot answer your question if we don't know how you define your terms.

Comment: Accurate means correct..

Comment: Okay, for $x=0.2234$, how many digits are *correct*?

Comment: Yes thats the question

Comment: You say "we know that $\Delta x\le \frac12\cdot 10^{-n}$ where $n$ is the number of the accurate digits."  What does $\Delta x$ mean?

Comment: absolute value of x

Comment: But if $x=0.2234$, then wouldn't its absolute value be $0.2234$?  I think you're misunderstanding what $\Delta x$ is and it seems that's why you can't answer the question.  I suggest that you review all your definitions and concepts again.

Comment: Sorry x is a value close to the value that we want to find. Δx is the absolute error of a value close to the original value x.They would be related this way:
Δ(Absolute error)=|X-x|≤Δx.

Comment: X is the original value

Answer (score 1):

You might be worried about carries.  If we had $x=0.1999, \Delta x=0.0002$, even the first digit might change.  Given your $x$ it is not a problem.

Added:  We are given a measurement of $0.2234 \pm 0.0002$, as that is what $\Delta x$ usually means, the possible error in measuring $x$.  We know the range is $0.2232$ to $0.2236$.  That shows the first three digits are accurate, as they do not change.  In my example, the range would be from $0.1997$ to $0.2001$

Comment: You answered the question in the post.  But it seems that the OP is not satisfied with your answer because the OP's *real* question is in the title.  (See our conversation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/778009/18398).)

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche:  I gave it a try

Answer (score 0):

You say that $\Delta x\le \frac12\cdot 10^{-n}$ where $n$ is the number of accurate digits.  You are given $\Delta x=0.2\cdot 10^{-3}$.  Thus, $0.2\cdot 10^{-3}\le 0.5\cdot 10^{-n}$.  Assuming that $n$ is an integer, then your $n$ could be $3$, or $2$, or $1$, or even $0$.  You need to give a more precise definition of *accurate* if you are looking for a specific value of $n$.  Are you saying that $n$ is the largest integer that satisfies the inequality?

Comment: If so, then $n=3$ and you would have three accurate digits.  This is consistent with Ross Millikan's answer.